# PDO::fetchAll() not returning records when using FETCH_ALL

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to PHP programming but have coded apps in .NET in the past.  I am just running through an example of retrieving a result set as an object.  For example, I have a class like the below in a file named myClass.php:

```
<?php
namespace MyNameSpace;

Class myClass{
   private $var1
           , $var2;

public function __constructor(){

}

//getters and setters for private variables below
} //end myClass
```

In a separate class, I have the below:

```
<?php
namespace OtherSpace;

require_once 'myClass.php';

$connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pwd);
$query = 'SELECT var1, var2 FROM someTable';
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'myClass');

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

print_r($result);
} // end class
```

However, nothing is sent to the browser window.  If I remove the setFetchMode statement from the code above then I do get a standard result set array sent back to the browser.

I don't understand what I am doing that would prevent the result set from loading into an array of the myClass objects.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Volodya: print_r shows `Array( )` for empty arrays, but if the fetch fails and you get a boolean false, that WILL print_r as an empty string.

Comment: `setFetchmode(..., 'MyNameSpace\myclass')`, perhaps? since your DB code is in `otherspace`, that space won't have a `myclass` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `new PDO` in the `\OtherSpace` namespace. It should be `\PDO` or you should use `use PDO;` it at the begining of the file after `namespace OtherSpace;`.

Maybe the `myClass` has the same problem because it is in the `\MyNameSpace` not in the `\OtherSpace`.

```
$statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, '\MyNameSpace\myClass');
```

So use full name of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using namespaces, you have to tell PDO the namespaced name:

```
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'MyNameSpace\myClass');
```

Methods do not know from which namespace they were called, only their own.